# Why does my navigation bar disappear when scrolling?

Tags: html, jquery, css, navigation, responsiveness

This is the website I'm currently have to work with: https://www.mpc.gov.my/home. Everything seems fine when you view using a desktop or big screen, but when you try to browse it using a mobile/smaller screen the navigation menu is giving the user a headache.

How can I fix it? I don't want the menu to disappear if I scroll down. Anyone get any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
  $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
  $(".menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">&nbsp;</a>");
  
  $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  
  $(".menu > ul > li").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    }
  });
  
  $(".menu-mobile").click(function(e) {
    $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".menu > ul > li").children("ul").hide();
  $(".menu > ul").removeClass('show-on-mobile');
});
```

```css
/*===================================
              Third Mega Menu
    =====================================*/

.menu {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}

.menu a.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  width: 19%;
  float: left;
}

.menu img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.menu-mobile {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-mobile:after {
  content: "\f0c9";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
  transform: translateY(-25%);
}

.menu-dropdown-icon:before {
  content: "\f0c9";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.menu>ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: right;
}

.menu>ul:before,
.menu>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  /* added- aidan */
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none!important;
}

.menu>ul>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  display: block;
}

.menu>ul>li:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul:before,
.menu>ul>li>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  background: none;
  float: left;
  list-style: none!important;
  /* added - aidan */
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li a {
  color: #777;
  padding: .2em 0;
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -10px;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul:before,
.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul:after {
  clear: both;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0;
  /*reduced to 0px - aidan */
  list-style: none!important;
  /*added -aidan */
  margin: 0!important;
  /*added !important - aidan*/
  font-size: .8em;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li a {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub {
  width: 300px;
  left: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub>li {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub>li a {
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.head-sub {
  font-weight: 700;
  /* added - aidan */
  color: #be1621!important;
  /* added - aidan */
}

.mobile-vue {
  display: none!important;
}

.desktop-vue {
  display: block!important;
  padding: 0px!important;
}

li.menu-dropdown-icon {
  margin: 0px!important;
}

.img-desktop-vue {
  max-width: 70%!important;
}

.tertiary-menu {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  /* added - aidan */
}


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
    Mobile style's
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .mobile-vue {
    display: block!important;
    /*added - aidan*/
  }
  .desktop-vue {
    display: none!important;
    /*added - aidan*/
    padding: unset;
  }
  li.menu-dropdown-icon {
    margin: unset!important;
    /*added - aidan*/
  }
  .menu-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-container .menu {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menu-mobile {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px 20px 0;
  }
  .menu-dropdown-icon:before {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu>ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu>ul>li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0!important;
    /* added - aidan */
  }
  .menu>ul>li a {
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 40px;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul.normal-sub {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin: 0!important;
    /* added - aidan*/
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li a {
    width: 90%;
    /* added - aidan */
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu>ul>li>ul>li>ul>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .menu .show-on-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .container-mobil {
    padding-left: unset!important;
    padding-right: unset!important;
  }
}

.fas,
.far {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="desktop-vue" style="background-color: #5ac6ca;text-align: center;"> <img src="/static_files/media_manager/1/Index-About-EN-1.png" class="img-desktop-vue"></a>
        <a href="#" class="mobile-vue">ABOUT MPC</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Corporate Info</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/background"><i class="fas fa-building"></i> Background</a></li>
              <li><a href="/vision-mission-and-objectives"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i> Vision, Mission &amp; Objectives</a></li>
              <li><a href="/board-of-directors"><i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i> Board of Directors</a></li>
              <li><a href="/management-mpc"><i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i> MPC Management</a></li>
              <li><a href="/organisational-structure"><i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i> Organisational Structure</a></li>
              <li><a href="/quality-policy"><i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i> Quality Policy</a></li>
              <li><a href="/client-charter"><i class="fas fa-list-alt"></i> Client Charter</a></li>
              <li><a href="/no-gift-policy"><i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i> No Gift Policy</a></li>
              <li><a href="/anti-corruption-plan"><i class="fas fa-file-contract"></i> Anti-Corruption Plan</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Contact Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/contact-us"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i> How To Contact Us?</a></li>
              <li><a href="/staff-directory"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Staff Directory</a></li>
              <li><a href="/frequently-asked-question"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> Frequently Asked Question</a></li>
              <li><a href="/career"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Career</a></li>
              <li><a href="/procurement"><i class="fas fa-chart-area"></i> Procurement</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Staff Access</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="http://staff.mpc.gov.my/"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Staff Portal</a></li>
              <li><a href="/prince"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Procurement Information Center (PRINCE)</a></li>
              <li><a href="/fin"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Finance Portal</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="desktop-vue" style="background-color: #f7902f;text-align: center;"> <img src="/static_files/media_manager/1/Index-Programme-EN-1.png" class="img-desktop-vue"></a>
        <a href="#" class="mobile-vue">PROGRAMMES &amp; SERVICES</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Productivity Initiatives</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/industry4wrd"><i class="fas fa-passport"></i> Industry4WRD Readiness Assessment</a></li>
              <li><a href="/team-excellence-convention"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-check"></i> Team Excellence Convention</a></li>
              <li><a href="/lean-management"><i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i> Lean Management</a></li>
              <li><a href="/enterprise-business-excellence"><i class="fas fa-cubes"></i> Enterprise Business Excellence</a></li>
              <li><a href="/productivity-excellence-recognition"><i class="fas fa-award"></i> Productivity Excellence Recognition</a></li>
              <li><a href="/mpc-certified-productivity-specialist-programme"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> MPC Certified Productivity Specialist Programme</a></li>
              <li><a href="/productivity-best-practices-case-studies-and-sharing"><i class="fas fa-poll"></i> Productivity Best Practices Case Studies and Sharing</a></li>
              <li><a href="/productivity-1010"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i> Productivity 1010</a></li>
              <li><a href="/negeri-produktif"><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> Negeri Produktif</a></li>
              <li><a href="/malaysia-productivity-blueprint"><i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i> Malaysia Productivity Blueprint</a></li>
              <li><a href="/productivity-nexus"><i class="fas fa-people-carry"></i> Productivity Nexus</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Productivity Online Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/digital-regulatory-notification"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Digital Regulatory Notification</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://oa.mpc.gov.my/prod/audit.nsf/reg.htm"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> QE Audit Application (Quality Environment)</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://bond.mpc.gov.my/"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Benchmarking Online Networking Database (BOND) Portal</a></li>
              <li><a href="/ezbe"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> ezBE Assessment Tool</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://upc.mpc.gov.my/"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Unified Public Consultation (UPC) Portal</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.wayup.my"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> WayUp Portal</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://mymudah.mpc.gov.my/"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> Smart Regulation (#MyMudah)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Business Virtual Advisory Services (VAS)</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/business-virtual-advisory-clinic"><i class="fas fa-business-time"></i> Business Virtual Advisory Clinics (VAC)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">MPC Webinar Sessions With Experts</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYBMIV_UwzSQuhk5rDPiBG2sLQIYWQ-bv"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> MPC Webinar Sessions With Experts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">P&amp;I Associate Membership</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/associate-membership"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> P&amp;I Associate Membership</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="" class="head-sub">Events Calendar</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/events-calendar"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Events Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="desktop-vue" style="background-color: #4d4f99;text-align: center;"> <img src="/static_files/media_manager/1/Index-Productivity-EN-1.png" class="img-desktop-vue"></a>
        <a href="#" class="mobile-vue">PRODUCTIVITY &amp; COMPETITIVENESS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Smart Regulation Towards A Robust Ecosystem</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/brvac"><i class="fas fa-business-time"></i> Business Regulation Virtual Advisory Clinic</a></li>
              <li><a href="/good-regulatory-practice"><i class="fas fa-landmark"></i> Good Regulatory Practice (GRP)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Workforce Of The Future</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="menushow"><a href="/espo"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i> e-Shared Prosperity Organization (eSPO)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Digitalisation And Technology</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/digitalisation-and-technology"><i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i> Digitalisation And Technology</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Productivity Mindset</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/programme-and-activity"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>  Programme and Activity</a></li>
              <li><a href="/sejahtera-productivity-culture-index"><i class="fas fa-users-cog"></i> Sejahtera Productivity Culture Index</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Incentive Structure</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/smart-incentives"><i class="fas fa-gifts"></i> Incentive Structure</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="desktop-vue" style="background-color: #88c05f;text-align: center;"> <img src="/static_files/media_manager/1/Index-Media-EN-1.png" class="img-desktop-vue"></a>
        <a href="#" class="mobile-vue">MEDIA &amp; PUBLICATION</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Media</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/press-release"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> Press Release</a></li>
              <li><a href="/speeches"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> Speeches</a></li>
              <li><a href="/audio-gallery"><i class="fas fa-music"></i> Audio Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="/video-gallery"><i class="fas fa-video"></i> Video Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="/enewsletter"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> e-Newsletter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" class="head-sub">Publication</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/productivity-performance"><i class="fas fa-network-wired"></i> Productivity Performance</a></li>
              <li><a href="/competitiveness-report"><i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i> Competitiveness Report</a></li>
              <li><a href="/annual-report"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Annual Report</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what happen when I scroll when in mobile view: https://youtu.be/UzLTU-Dzhes

Comment: I honestly couldn't understand the question. You said that in desktop/big screens it runs fine but the nav menu wasn't appearing when I opened the website (because of what was already answered down: `display: none`) and you said that in mobile it wasn't working but in fact it is working there (it just looks a bit weird).

Comment: No. YOu can see this video https://youtu.be/UzLTU-Dzhes 

The navigation menu tend to hidden when i scroll down.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I can't replicate the bug. I've tried on two phones and in the responsive mode in my browser. The navigation menu doesn't disappear like it is disappearing for you. It could be something with your browser version or a mobile model thing.

Comment: I think I;ve fixed that on my own but i dunno if that the real solution. I just disable the last part in the jquery script. -->   

  $(".menu > ul > li").children("ul").hide();
  $(".menu > ul").removeClass('show-on-mobile');

Answer (score 1):

if you inspect in your website, you can see that there is a display none in the menu :

```
.menu-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

remove it and everything will work fine

Comment: This is not what im looking for. The menu is supposed to be for mobile view so thats why its hidden as a default. 

Maybe you can get the idea when u see this video https://youtu.be/UzLTU-Dzhes

Comment: you can do position fixed : exemple : `@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)
.menu-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
}`

Comment: Tried that and not working. If I do that, I cannot scroll the page at all.

Comment: maybe can try this one, `<div class="menu-container" style="position: sticky; top: 0; `       `z-index: 12;">` Please take note that the position: sticky does not support Internet Explorer, Edge 15 and earlier versions.